# FontAwesome hover effect not working

Tags: html, css, hover, font-awesome

I'm trying to get a simple hover effect on a button, which already works for the button background & text, but not for the FontAwesome-Icon. The Icon only appears with non-hover. I already tried most combinations e.g.

```
fa-chevron-right:hover:before {color: X;}
```

or

```
.vc_btn-icon3:hover .fa-chevron-right { color: X;}
```

and many other combinations, but I can't get it to work the right way. May you tell me where my mistake is and how it has to look like? Here is what I already get. Be aware, cause I am using a wordpress-theme, therefore there are many classes. For me as a newcomer it makes it even harder to geht things right :/

HTML

```
 <div class="shortcode-action-container action-button">
    <a href="LINK" class="btn-shortcode dt-btn-l dt-btn default-btn-color
     default-btn-hover-color default-btn-bg-color default-btn-bg-hover-color 
    fadeIn animate-element animation-builder" 
    target="_blank" id="dt-btn-1">
    <span>Mehr Informationen 
    <i class="vc_btn3-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a></div>
```

CSS

```
#dt-btn-1 {
background-color:#002E5B;
color: #fff;
font-family: Montserrat;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 23px;
font-weight: 700;
background: #002E5B;
border: solid 3px transparent;
padding: 8px 21px;
}

.vc_btn3-icon {
margin-left: 0.5em;
margin-right: 0px !important;

.fa-chevron-right:before {
font-family: FontAwesome;
color: #002e5b;
content: "\f054";
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
color: #fde428;
}

#dt-btn-1:hover {
background: none;
background: transparent !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
border-color: #fff !important;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #002e5b !important;
border: solid 3px #fff;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pardon, I should also add that I just want to change the color of the FontAwesome-Icon when hovered. The icon appears without hover effect. With hover effect there is no icon or the icon may have the same background color like the whole background

Comment: as this is your 1st post and seems to be solved, you might click on the tick mark beside @Aziz answer to accept it. It would probably deserve an upvote as well to show appreciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to target the icon is by using the following selector:

```
#dt-btn-1:hover .fa-chevron-right:before { ... }
```

Here is a working demo:

```css
a {text-decoration: none;}

#dt-btn-1 {
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #002E5B;
  border: solid 3px transparent;
  padding: 8px 21px;
}

.vc_btn3-icon {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.fa-chevron-right:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: #002e5b;
  content: "\f054";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #fde428;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#dt-btn-1:hover {
  background: none;
  background: transparent !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #002e5b !important;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#dt-btn-1:hover .fa-chevron-right:before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="shortcode-action-container action-button">
  <a href="LINK" class="btn-shortcode dt-btn-l dt-btn default-btn-color
     default-btn-hover-color default-btn-bg-color default-btn-bg-hover-color 
    fadeIn animate-element animation-builder" target="_blank" id="dt-btn-1">
    <span>
      Mehr Informationen
      <i class="vc_btn3-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Please note that your CSS code is invalid because:

> ```
> .vc_btn3-icon {
> margin-left: 0.5em;
> margin-right: 0px !important;
> ```
>
> **}** <- missing
>
> ```
> .fa-chevron-right:before {
> ```

[**working jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/puLjskhe/)

Comment: Hey Aziz, 
you made my day! Is there a way to find the right selectors easily, maybe with a tool like firebug or sth. like that? Anyway, your solution worked well. Thank you so much for your help, I already have spent a couple of hours just to find the right css selectors! Thanks! :)

Comment: You can always use the dev inspector to see which element you need to target, you can even play with its CSS live with the `style` window to make sure that the change you want to make will work. As for `:hover`, it is always recommended to start with the parent (usually anchor tag or button) then add the child element you want to be changed in hover state, like this: `parent:hover child { change; }` in your case, the parent is `#dt-btn-1` and the child we wanted to change was `.fa-chevron-right:before`

Comment: Thank you so much Aziz, I will keep that in mind! Have a great night, day, week, month & year. I wish you the best :)

Comment: Happy to help! If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: For sure, my friend. It was my first post, here we go!

Comment: @Aziz, you also made my day! Wonderful answer.